# Raspberry Pi 2 stuck on boot

Tags: raspbian

[image]

Rasp PI 2 stuck on boot. The red light is stable and green light flash few times during start up and later stopped. Then screen also freezed. Any Idea?

EDIT : It is solved. Change a new power supply with higher ampere and everything works fine.

Comment: The pattern with your lights is normal; two green flashes indicates no problems, then it will flash intermittently when reading from the SD card.  There are no errors on that screen pic, either, so this is odd.  If you have a keyboard plugged in, try cycling through the first six F-keys with alt-ctrl held down.  Probably `init` has not started, so you will get a blank screen on everything but F1.  But this will indicate the kernel is responsive.  If you cannot switch to a blank screen (i.e., nothing happens) then is isn't.

Comment: And you are sure that there is no little "rainbow-colored" square pulsing in the right top corner of your screen either (it might have been cut off on your image)? If that's there, then the rPi cannot pull enough power from your power supply - I've seen it stop functioning at a random place that way - you'd need to find a more powerful 5V usb power supply (I use a 2.2Amp rated one).

Comment: Plugged in keyboard but keyboard not working.. cant type anything. There is little rainbow-colored square in the right top corner. I using a 5V 2.4A power supply.

Comment: Sounds like you might have a dodgy power supply if the rainbow square is showing. Have you got a different one?

Comment: I don't have a different one except a lower amp one(Tested cant work also). So my power supply is the problem? What type of power supply should i get?

Comment: 5V / 2.2 A *should* be enough; if you have anything USB plugged into the pi try without, but likely either the supply or the pi are defective.

Comment: Just so you feel better - I had several rPi B+'s running happily on a 5V 1.5A power supply. Switched them over to rPi 2's and got the flashing rainbow square on all of them. Went to 5V 2.2A and they are trucking along merrily without issues. This is with a wired keyboard, wired mouse and usb WiFi dongle attached.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is likely caused by an undersupply of current. As per the conversation in the comments - you are seeing a rainbow-colored square in the top right corner of your screen (not on your picture) which is the rPi telling you that it doesn't have enough power supplied to it. Switch to a more powerful supply such as [this 5V 2.2A supply](http://www.mcmelectronics.com/product/28-17985) and it will likely boot all the way. Or alternatively remove some of your USB peripherals (disk, wifi, mouse) to reduce the power consumption of your setup.

EDIT: And if you are indeed already using a 5V 2.4A supply, you have a faulty supply, because 2.4A should be enough to boot an rPi with keyboard, mouse and WiFi attached. I use a cheap USB volt/amp meter ([like this one](http://www.ebay.com/itm/1pcs-USB-Current-Tester-USB-voltmeter-USB-ammeter-Ampere-Meter-blue-color-/331534363972?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item4d30fced44)) in combination with a microUSB-to-USB adapter to check how much amps my power supplies provide - sometimes what they claim they deliver is far from what they actually deliver, the Amp rating might be maximum "burst" or "peak" Amps, not the continuous supply capability.

Comment: FTR, it seems to be important whether the rainbow square just appears in a corner (indicates power-supply brownout), or you _only_ get such a square on the video output when trying to boot. That, [apparently](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=100078), would then be a software issue caused by an incompatible kernel. Quite confusing that they use such a square to signal two completely different problems!